# Service is not wroking

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have two web services on the server. When i run the service url 
http://www.solentvehicleleasing.co.uk/solentwebservice.asmx/GetLeasingPriceForTechinalPageByDerID.  Its give service messsage .

"Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetLeasingPriceForTechinalPageByDerID'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetLeasingPriceForTechinalPageByDerID'."

The above error fine for  the service.

But on the same server when i run the another service  http://www.solentcarleasing.co.uk/solentwebservice.asmx/GetLeasingPriceForTechinalPageByDerID.  The return 404 error.

I am using MVC 3 and call the service using jquery ajax method.

Can anyone help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are your DNS settings for www.solentcarleasing.co.uk?  Does that point to the same directory as www.solentvehicleleasing.co.uk?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, web services never worked having a URL set up that way.  You can view the service details:  http://www.solentcarleasing.co.uk/solentwebservice.asmx?op=GetLeasingPriceForTechinalPageByDerID

Within Visual Studio, you'll have to add the service and then call it from code.  You can't just navigate to is via *.asmx/ServiceMethodName

Comment: Thanks for reply .. but i am calling the  service using Jquery Ajax mathod. If check the error console .. the found that it throw 404 error

Comment: Thanks for reply .. but i am calling the  service using Jquery Ajax method and its working fine on my  local machine but creating issue on the server. If check the error console .. the found that it throw 404 error